# Any way for $location.search() to reset or clear out when a new URL is navigated to?

Tags: angularjs

After looking through the documentation, I think I have missed a concept that eludes me.  In AngularJS, $location.search() returns a getter/setter that enables me to manipulate the AngularJS search "query string"--that is, the part of the URL after the #!...? (in "hash-bang mode").  Seems easy enough.

Suppose I navigate to a page `#!/budgets` where I have manipulated this; for example:

```
vm.filterOptions = $location.search();
vm.filterOptions.status = vm.filterOptions.status || "active";
```

So now, the filterOptions.status will have a value, and $location.search().status will have the same value.

I gather that the URL in the location bar does not change at that point, and thus we have $location.search()'s contents that don't match the URL in the location bar.  I need to call $location.search($location.search()) or similar to actually trigger a location change.  Fine, but is this behavior spelled out somewhere?

Then, if I then click an ordinary link, like  `<a href="#!/products">`, the contents of $location.search() are *retained* even though the new URL has nothing in search.  Also, if I click a link that has a search term, like `<a href="#!/products?foo=bar">`, the contents of $location.search() are *still retained, in addition to* the new property `foo` shown in the URL.  This strikes me as quite odd, though I can see where `<a href="...` and `$location.search()...` are both in effect manipulating the URL, so there is likely a good reason that I am missing.  Can you help me out?

**Is there a setting or a better way to get AngularJS $location.search() to reset or clear out when a new URL is navigated to**, especially via ordinary `<a>` links?  What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Patrick, trying to understand your question.  What is the need of the URL, are you trying to control what the URL looks like, are you trying to navigate to a specific URL, what is the purpose of the $locatoin.search()?

Comment: I think you may be looking for ngRoute, which is related to the $location, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: $location.search() holds properties that are automatically appended onto the ?... portion of the URL.  I am using them to filter items on my page.

Answer (score 0):

While I am still confused as to why the properties on `$location.search()` are preserved across `<a href="#...">` links, I think I have found a solution.

Instead of manipulating the properties of `$location.search()`, **I am now manipulating a copy of it, via `var terms = angular.copy($location.search());`.**  Then, when I want to make it effective, I call `$location.search(terms);`.  Such edits are *not* carried across `<a href="#...">` links.  I'm still confused as to why edits to the properties of `$location.search()` are carried across `<a href="#...">` links, but at least I have a good solution.